# Intellij auto-complete spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, ide

I can't install plugin spring-boot to auto-complete my code.
I don´t know how to do it. Anybody can teach me?

Comment: you must not have the Ultimate Edition? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-boot.html

Comment: I did not know, thanks